# fill NA of a column with elements of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spark-koalas

i'm in this situation,
my df is like that

```
    A   B   
0   0.0 2.0 
1   3.0 4.0 
2   NaN 1.0 
3   2.0 NaN 
4   NaN 1.0 
5   4.8 NaN 
6   NaN 1.0
```

and i want to apply this line of code:
`df['A'] = df['B'].fillna(df['A'])`

and I expect a workflow and final output like that:

```
    A   B   
0   2.0 2.0 
1   4.0 4.0 
2   1.0 1.0 
3   NaN NaN 
4   1.0 1.0 
5   NaN NaN 
6   1.0 1.0 

    A   B   
0   2.0 2.0 
1   4.0 4.0 
2   1.0 1.0 
3   2.0 NaN 
4   1.0 1.0 
5   4.8 NaN 
6   1.0 1.0
```

but I receive this error:

`TypeError: Unsupported type Series`

probably because each time there is an NA it tries to fill it with the whole series and not with the single element with the same index of the B column.

I receive the same error with a syntax like that:
`df['C'] = df['B'].fillna(df['A'])`
so the problem seems not to be the fact that I'm first changing the values of A with the ones of B and then trying to fill the "B" NA with the values of a column that is technically the same as B

I'm in a databricks environment and I'm working with koalas data frames but they work as the pandas ones.
can you help me?

Comment: Work for me `df['A'] = df['B'].fillna(df['A'])`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option

Suppose the following dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'State':[1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
                         'Sno Center': ["Guntur", "Nellore", "Visakhapatnam", "Biswanath", "Doom-Dooma", "Guntur", "Labac-Silchar", "Numaligarh", "Sibsagar", "Munger-Jamalpu"], 
                         'Mar-21': [121, 118.8, 131.6, 123.7, 127.8, 125.9, 114.2, 114.2, 117.7, 117.7],
                         'Apr-21': [121.1, 118.3, 131.5, np.NaN, 128.2, 128.2, 115.4, 115.1, np.NaN, 118.3]})

df
State   Sno Center      Mar-21  Apr-21
0   1   Guntur          121.0   121.1
1   2   Nellore         118.8   118.3
2   3   Visakhapatnam   131.6   131.5
3   4   Biswanath       123.7   NaN
4   5   Doom-Dooma      127.8   128.2
5   6   Guntur          125.9   128.2
6   7   Labac-Silchar   114.2   115.4
7   8   Numaligarh      114.2   115.1
8   9   Sibsagar        117.7   NaN
9   10  Munger-Jamalpu  117.7   118.3
```

Then

```
df.loc[(df["Mar-21"].notnull()) & (df["Apr-21"].isna()), "Apr-21"] = df["Mar-21"]

df
State   Sno Center      Mar-21  Apr-21
0   1   Guntur          121.0   121.1
1   2   Nellore         118.8   118.3
2   3   Visakhapatnam   131.6   131.5
3   4   Biswanath       123.7   123.7
4   5   Doom-Dooma      127.8   128.2
5   6   Guntur          125.9   128.2
6   7   Labac-Silchar   114.2   115.4
7   8   Numaligarh      114.2   115.1
8   9   Sibsagar        117.7   117.7
9   10  Munger-Jamalpu  117.7   118.3
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

try with `max()`:

```
df['A']=df[['A','B']].max(axis=1)
```

output of `df`:

```
    A       B
0   2.0     2.0
1   4.0     4.0
2   1.0     1.0
3   2.0     NaN
4   1.0     1.0
5   4.8     NaN
6   1.0     1.0
```